# regex match a line with more than 2 non-digits including ^

Tags: regex

I want to match lines with negative numbers or/and decimal numbers with a `^`.

```
-1.2^-2.4  
-12^2.4  
-1^2
```

but not

```
1^2
1+2
```

I got `[\^\D*]{2,}` but it is not working

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are looking for something like the following.

```
^(?=.*\D{2,})[-.^\d]+$
```

[Live Demo](http://regex101.com/r/eU0oI4/1)

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
/^((-\d+|\.\d+)\^|.+\^(-\d+|\.\d+))/
```

matches a negative or decimal number followed by ^ or a ^ followed by a negative or decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
^-?\d+(\.\d+)?\^-?\d+(\.\d+)?$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/6QftwAMBRg)